# PicketLink - NoClassDefFound: org/picketlink/idm/config/StoreConfiguration

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jboss, noclassdeffounderror, picketlink

I'm beginning to migrate my [Seam](http://seamframework.org/) 2.3 app over to JavaEE 6, and as part of that will be using [PicketLink](http://picketlink.org/) 2.5.0 and [PicketBox](http://picketbox.jboss.org/) 5.0 for security, particularly the IDM component.  I'm trying to make use of the JPA Identity Store, and have created my own entities with the appropriate annotations.  However, when I attempt to add a user, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/picketlink/idm/config/StoreConfiguration
```

I've looked in the JAR files, and sure enough I don't see this object.  I'm using PicketBox 5.0.  Is this a known issue with this combination of PicketLink and PicketBox?  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Is this object located in a different JAR?  The code to create my user looks like this:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.identityManager().jpaStore();

PicketBoxConfiguration config = builder.build();
DefaultPicketBoxManager picketBoxManager = new DefaultPicketBoxManager(
        config);

picketBoxManager.start();

EntityManagerPropagationContext.set(this.entityManager);

IdentityManager idm = picketBoxManager.getIdentityManager();

    SimpleUser user = new SimpleUser("testuser");
    idm.add(user);
    System.out.println("User added");
```

**UPDATE:**  A bit more info on my setup...

I have downloaded PicketLink 2.5.0beta6 and PicketBox 5.0.0.  All the relevant JARs are maintained within my EAR file, which is deployed on JBoss EAP 6.1.  When I run my code, I see the following Exception thrown:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/picketlink/idm/config/StoreConfiguration
    org.picketbox.core.AbstractPicketBoxManager.doStart(AbstractPicketBoxManager.java:244)
    org.picketbox.core.AbstractPicketBoxLifeCycle.start(AbstractPicketBoxLifeCycle.java:53)
    net.test.services.TestEJB.doTest(TestEJB.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374)
    org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:129)
    org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:137)
    org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58)
    org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

...

JBWEB000071: root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.picketlink.idm.config.StoreConfiguration from [Module "deployment.TestApp-ear.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119)
    org.picketbox.core.AbstractPicketBoxManager.doStart(AbstractPicketBoxManager.java:244)
    org.picketbox.core.AbstractPicketBoxLifeCycle.start(AbstractPicketBoxLifeCycle.java:53)
    net.test.services.TestEJB.doTest(TestEJB.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `org.picketlink` as a module dependency?

Comment: I have a newer version (2.5.0beta6) of picketlink embedded in the EAR.  That's the one I want to use, not the one that comes with JBoss EAP 6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to locate documentation on the JBoss site that explained how to upgrade the PicketLink libraries within JBoss EAP 6.1.  That solved everything.